# System.Web.DynamicData in .NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

We use System.Web.DynamicData in .NET 4.x.
This doesn't exist in .NET 6.0

This is our .NET 4.x code:

```
using System.Web.DynamicData;

namespace MyCode.Entities
{
   [TableName("Lists")]
```

What replaces the System.Web.DynamicData Namespace in .NET 6 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please tell me which codes you want to replace in .Net 6? Since this namespace is using web form related control , but ,net 6 there is no web form .

Comment: I believe you'll want ASP.NET Core OData: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio

Comment: dotnetcore discontinued web forms, but there is an alternative with Razor/Mvc in dotnet core  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, and so on parallels her https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi all, I added the code snippet from .NET 4.x in the original post. We use TableName from System.Web.DynamicData

Comment: Where you use this entity table name?  Since Asp.net core we have ef core, it also contains the sql table related attribute.  Besides, if you move from .net to .net core, most of the codes need be re-design.